# Serialize PHP => Unserialize JAVA / Serialize for php in string format

Tags: java, php, arrays, serialization, deserialization

I have an array in php of this format:

```
<?php
$value = array("id" => 42, "user" => "superman");
echo serialize($value); 
?>
```

Serialized :

```
a:2:{s:2:"id";i:42;s:4:"user";s:8:"superman";}
```

I receive this into a `String` in java.
How I can do for deserialize this in java ?
I know the `implements Serializable` in java but not work in this case.

I want to create an object in this kind of format :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Serial implements Serializable{
    private int mId;
    private String mUser;

    public Serial(int mId, String mUser) {
        super();
        this.mId = mId;
        this.mUser = mUser;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.mId = id;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return mUser;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.mUser = user;
    }
}
```

After that I want to create another time the `String` serialized from the Java object for deserialize in PHP;

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Related/duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743402/unserialize-in-java-a-serialized-php-object). Use a universal format like JSON.

Comment: Yea use a serialsation format which is supported on both sides. Java Serializable means you can serialize the binary state of the object to transfer it inside the java world ;) But for example a given JSON String could be parsed as JSON in your constructor of your pojo to fill up the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't natively read one languages serialised objects with another language (languages each have their own serialisation protocols/format, there is no guarantee they can read one-anothers format), Java serialised objects are serialised to a binary format and PHP your provided text format.

There are libraries such as [Google's protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) that you can use, they don't officially support PHP, however there are [3rd party libraries](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) which provide Protocol Buffer support for PHP.

> Protocol buffers are Google's **language-neutral**, **platform-neutral**,
>   extensible **mechanism for serializing structured data** – think XML, but
>   smaller, faster, and simpler. You define how you want your data to be
>   structured once, then you can use special generated source code to
>   easily write and read your structured data to and from a variety of
>   data streams and using a variety of languages – Java, C++, or Python.

If you aren't fond of that, you will need to develop your own protocol for reading PHPs serialised objects into a Java object, you may be able to do this with a modified JSON library as I don't believe that `s:2:"id";` from your sample serialised object is valid JSON. There exists a [library](http://code.google.com/p/serialized-php-parser/) for doing this using Java, however the PHP serialisation format isn't 'safe' as it can contain null values, so I would advise against it.

Comment: Thanks is good for the parting ! Thanks a lot ! For help I do the serialization manually. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for you, but could be useful for others (including me) :

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743402/unserialize-in-java-a-serialized-php-object), which has a lot of answers.
For those who don't have time to read, here are the main links it leads to :

1- [A static class for PHP de/serialization](https://www.drupal.org/node/319482)

2- [The Pherialize class with its satellite classes](https://github.com/kayahr/pherialize/)

**BUT** as @Robadob (and all devs) said it, the most reliable method to do this kind of job is to use a standard format.