# How to read php Doctrine2 type (DC2type) array in java?

Tags: java, php, doctrine-orm

I am new in java

I have a DC2type:array (doctine2 array saved from my PHP app)

```
a:4:{i:0;s:4:"1117";i:1;s:4:"1135";i:2;s:5:"14138";i:3;s:5:"52337";}
```

I am able to retrieve this value using PHP code.
Now I have to get it using java.
Is there any direct functions to convert this DC2type:array format into an array in java ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104274/serialize-php-unserialize-java-serialize-for-php-in-string-format