# Parse a string of a peculiar format

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a legacy application which stores data in the database in a peculiar format

For example I have following string

```
a:4:{i:0;s:4:"a’";i:1;s:6:"abcdef";i:2;s:5:"abcde";i:3;s:3:"xyz";}
```

To signify the following four individual strings:

1. a’
2. abcdef
3. abcde
4. xyz

A cursory glance shows that the argument after s is meant to be the length of the corresponding string. However this is not in the case of first string where the **expected argument after s should be 2 but is instead 4**.

As of now I was parsing this string by the following method:

First via regex get `i:0;s:4:"a’";i:1;s:6:"abcdef";i:2;s:5:"abcde";i:3;s:3:"xyz";`

Thereafter via regex `^i:\d+;s:(\d+):"(.+)$` get `len = 4` and `a’";i:1;s:6:"abcdef";i:2;s:5:"abcde";i:3;s:3:"xyz";` get the first option by taking first 4 characters (which would not work here since `len` should be 2), and then get `i:1;s:6:"abcdef";i:2;s:5:"abcde";i:3;s:3:"xyz";` and iterate furthur.

I also had initially tried to parse everything at once via regex `i:\d*;s:\d*:"([^;]*)";` but this won't work if the string contains this very pattern (the argument after s is supposed to be the definite way to do this).

Also I checked that if the string is `a’Δ` then the argument becomes 6.

**How would you advise me to tackle such strings (with special characters) and can you tell me what is this format and how to parse it?**

PS: I am using java.

Comment: The format seems simple enough to manually create a state automaton-based parser for it.

Comment: Looks like `i=integer`, `s=string`,`s:n = string of size n`, `a=object` etc. btw, I don't think that regex is intended to parse this.

Comment: `i` is probably the index of the entry

Comment: @biziclop Oh yes, `a:4` would be for `array` of size 4 and each `i:` would be the index in this array.

Comment: And the number after `s:` is the number of bytes the following string consists of in UTF-8. Hence `s:4:"a’"`, because the `’` apostrophe character corresponds to the `0xE2 0x80 0x99` byte sequence in UTF-8.

Comment: do you have other examples? maybe the length of a' is a mistake

Comment: @1010 No, it isn't a mistake, it just refers to UTF-8 multi-byte sequences.

Comment: you are right, that apostrophe is %u2019

Comment: given these are serialized objects, you may need a real parser if your data may contain more than arrays of strings.

Comment: It turns out this is the standard PHP serialization format, and as such it's a duplicate of the linked question. Thanks to @SilentDariusz for pointing it out.

Comment: I agree but I now reopened the question and SO doesn't allow me to mark it as duplicate of the other. Eh.

Comment: @biziclop probably voting will help.. voted for duplicate :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is serialized PHP array. So all You need is to unserialize it.

Using regexp can easily lead to situation when You won't cover some data format that is implemented in serialize funcion used here.

Think this topic helps: [Serialize PHP => Unserialize JAVA / Serialize for php in string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104274/serialize-php-unserialize-java-serialize-for-php-in-string-format)

Comment: You should add a bit more detail for this to be a good answer.

Comment: I think the real answer is in linked question. Don't want to copy it nor take credits for someone elses knowledge.

Comment: @karthikmanchala I'm sure your regexp can be broken with ease. A real parser is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [java implementation for deserializing php serialized objects (by google).](https://code.google.com/p/serialized-php-parser/)

If you want a regex you can use the following:

```
i:\d+;s:\d+:"([^"]*)";
```

And extract the required with `$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yE4yT4/2)