# Groovy equivalent for php's unserialize

Tags: serialization, groovy

I am working with serialized data from Wordpress database. Strings created with PHP serialize function and look something like this:

a:4:{s:6:"weight";s:2:"15";s:6:"length";s:1:"8";s:5:"width";s:1:"8";s:6:"height";s:2:"17";}

Is there a way to deserialize this in Groovy? or is this not a product of standardized serialization?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks similar to JSON but definitely isn't. No idea how to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using the [`pherialize` library](https://github.com/kayahr/pherialize)

```
@GrabResolver( name='Ailis', root='http://nexus.ailis.de/content/groups/public' )
@Grab( 'de.ailis.pherialize:pherialize:1.2.1' )
import de.ailis.pherialize.*

def phpValue = 'a:4:{s:6:"weight";s:2:"15";s:6:"length";s:1:"8";s:5:"width";s:1:"8";s:6:"height";s:2:"17";}'

def groovyMap = Pherialize.unserialize( phpValue ).toArray().collectEntries { k, v ->
    [ k.toType( k.type ), v.toType( v.type ) ]
}

assert groovyMap == [ weight:'15', length:'8', width:'8', height:'17' ]
```

Though if possible, I'd suggest you share data between the two in a format they both natively speak (json?)

Answer (score 1):

There [was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743402/unserialize-in-java-a-serialized-php-object) a similar question already. It seems that there are parsers for PHP serialization implemented in java. Every java lib can used with groovy, so solving this shouldn't be a problem. On of the libraries can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/serialized-php-parser/)