# Can't parse single letter and single number json response

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress, parsing

I've an issue with a Json Response in Android. The json I'm getting is:

```
"latlng": [
"s:78:\"a:2:{s:3:\"lat\";s:18:\"40.653198478383175\";s:3:\"lng\";s:18:\"-73.95414308015137\";}\";"
],
```

and I should be getting something like this:

```
"latlng": {
     "address": "8, Bolivia",
     "lat": "-10.92968864676556",
     "lng": "-65.7861328125"
},
```

And looks like a big string with some "supposed" json objects with single letters and single numbers.

I can't find the way to parse this information with the most used json parsers for android.

I'm using the UTF-8 in Android when trying to parse it, but not change at all.

This is an issue server side? My client is using a wordpress site with WP JSON REST API but this info comes from a Theme with custom meta values and meta keys.

How could I parse this info in Android? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Please, check the full json response here: http://pastebin.com/Xm7w3UKG and don't post me "that not a json response" because it's a valid json response.

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data`. The string is incorrect.

Comment: Is just a fragment of all the json response... I can't post the entire thing here.

Here you have a pastebin of all the json response: http://pastebin.com/Xm7w3UKG

And you'll see that is a valid json response.

Comment: The error comes from the entire JSON response, or just the chunk contained within the `latlng` key?

Comment: The error comes from the custom meta values of the theme. On the pastebin I've posted you can check it in line 105 "meta" key all the "javo_header_type": etc have the same issue... every single response is a string.

The json object name when starts is perfect, I can get those ones... but not the info inside of it (it's an array of strings, or looks like that). From line 114 you can check that behavior http://pastebin.com/Xm7w3UKG

Comment: Can you show the code that receives and parses the JSON and show how you are logging it?

Comment: The data format is php serialization, or made with phps function `serialize()`. If you are not able to change that to `json_encode` on server side, i suggest you look up å way to parse php serialization in java. I found this old stackthread you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743402/unserialize-in-java-a-serialized-php-object

Comment: Thank you so much Morten, didn't know about that. Well... I'll ask access to server side and to the theme creator so I can change that or following that thread (good info BTW)