# PHP serialzed array parser to Java object

Tags: java, php, mysql, json, spring

I need to parse PHP serialized array string to java. For ex.

```
`a:7:{
    s:3:'Mon';a:2:{s:9:'open_time';s:5:'00:00';s:10:'close_time';s:5:'24:00';}
    s:3:'Tue';a:2{s:9:'open_time';s:5:'00:00';s:10:'close_time';s:5:'24:00';}
    s:3:'Wed';a:2{s:9:'open_time';s:5:'00:00';s:10:'close_time';s:5:'24:00';}
    s:3:'Thu';a:2{s:9:'open_time';s:5:'00:00';s:10:'close_time';s:5:'24:00';}
    s:3:'Fri';a:2{s:9:'open_time';s:5:'00:00';s:10:'close_time';s:5:'24:00';}
    s:3:'Sat';a:2{s:9:'open_time';s:5:'00:00';s:10:'close_time';s:5:'24:00';}
    s:3:'Sun';a:2:{s:9:'open_time';s:5:'00:00';s:10:'close_time';s:5:'24:00';}
}
```

Result must be like

```
    List<Worktime> weekdays
    `          Worktime{
    String day;
    String openTime;
String closeTime;
    }
```

Comment: please edit your question so it would be easier to read. and elaborate regarding your question/problem.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/743402/2298301

Comment: the main differnce that there is array inside the array